# Why don't indices seem to help this in this join (SQL Server 2008R2)?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, join, indexing

I've been trying to make some hands-on learning about indices, since I plan to give some lectures about them next semester. I have read the important chapters in Ramakrishnan & Gehrke, and some pages on the internet, including SQL Server documentation. I thought I had a good enough theoretical understanding of the subject, but when I began making experiments with SQL Server 2008 R2 I had some trouble to verify them.

At this point, I still want to reread the chapters from R&G on query evaluation, namely chapters 12-15, but I wanted to run these tests now to see if I'm getting it right.

I am using the AdventureWorks database, but I altered it somewhat to create examples. My goal is to give the students an empirical exploration of the subject, by giving them similar queries to compare over similar tables and deduce the influence of the indices in their performance. Towards that, I created three tables with data based on `Sales.SalesOrderDetail`:

- table 1 (`newDetailsTable`) has a clustered index on the primary key `(SalesOrderId, SalesOrderDetailId`;
- table 2 (`newDetailsTable_noIndex`) has no index and then on a second phase in the tests I create a non-clustered index on it on `ProductId`, including `OrderQty` and `PriceUnit`
- table 3 (`newDetailsTable_sortedInsert`) has the same clustered index as table 1 and in a second phase the same non-clustered index as table 2 (both at the same time)

In table 1 and 3, the clustered index is created through a primary key constraint. Table 2 does not have a primary key.

I removed every check, default and foreign key constraints, and the automatic calculations for certain columns, so that the time spent in the queries should be only from finding the right records and not checking integrity.

These tables are loaded with the rows of a staging table that multiplies the initial rows of `SalesOrderDetail`. They have 3882144. These are created by

```
select * into stagingTable from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

and then a series of inserts like

```
INSERT INTO stagingtable (...) SELECT (...) FROM stagingTable,
```

where the select includes, in the position for `[SalesOrderDetailID], [SalesOrderDetailID] + 1000000`.

Successive iterations replace this added value by its double, until the last is 16000000.

I also created three copies of `Sales.salesOrderHeader`. None of them have primary keys. I also eliminated foreign keys, check and default constraints as before.

- table 1 (`newHeaderTable`) has no index at all
- table 2 (`newHeaderTable_withIndex`) has a non-clustered index on `SalesOrderId`
- table 3 (`newHeaderTable_withClustIndex`) has a clustered index on `SalesOrderId`.

I ran each of the following queries twice each:

```
/*                Details Table Clustered*/
/*Header Table Heap - No Indexes*/
select d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.SalesOrderID from NewDetailsTable d join newHeaderTable h on d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
/*Header Table Clustered*/
select d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.SalesOrderID from NewDetailsTable d join newHeaderTable_withClustIndex h on d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
/*Header Table Heap with NCI*/
select d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.SalesOrderID from NewDetailsTable d join newHeaderTable_withIndex h on d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID

/*                Details Table Heap*/
/*Header Table Heap - No Indexes*/
select d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.SalesOrderID from NewDetailsTable_noIndex d join newHeaderTable h on d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
/*Header Table Clustered*/
select d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.SalesOrderID from NewDetailsTable_noIndex d join newHeaderTable_withClustIndex h on d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
/*Header Table Heap with NCI*/
select d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.SalesOrderID from NewDetailsTable_noIndex d join newHeaderTable_withIndex h on d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
```

[image: Plan Images]

I expected that the fourth line, having no usable indices in either of the tables, would be much slower than the others. But in fact, they've all been around the same time more or less, 2m12s on my computer.

I checked the execution plans for line 1 and I see a merge join after a clustered index scan and a table scan

I checked the execution plans for line 4 and I see a hash match after two table scans.

So the plans seem consistent with what is expected, but the times do not differ in much. I also checked the statistics (I'm using both statistics time on and statistics io on) and the physical reads in line 4 are at 0! Also, I've ran all queries immediately after executing

```
dbcc freesystemcache ('All')
go
dbcc dropcleanbuffers
go
```

So, why are the times the same? Do I need more or less rows? Is it coincidence, or should I be filtering rows before the join? I remember that some years ago I was playing with a MySql database where I had retailer data similar to AW. I had about 1m rows in details, and 100k rows in headers. Initially the database had no indices and when I put them in the chages were dramatic. Why am I not getting that behaviour here?

Thanks all.
And Merry Holidays for you.

P.S: I can provide scripts as needed. I only didn't because this is long already.

---

Ok, I have some trouble editing a previous comment of mine. Anyway, I uploaded the scripts. They're here:
https://gist.github.com/1514951

Also, I followed Marc_s's suggestion, but I didn't get the results I expected. 
I reduced the columns, and instead of

```
SELECT *
```

I made

```
SELECT d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.SalesOrderID  FROM NewDetailsTable d JOIN newHeaderTable h ON d.SalesOrderID = h.salesOrderId
```

and also

```
select d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.SalesOrderID from NewDetailsTable_noIndex d join newHeaderTable h on d.SalesOrderID = h.salesOrderId
```

I updated stats. To note: the table `newHEaderTable` does not have indices. Then, `NewDetailsTable` has a clustered primary key index on `SalesOrderId, SalesOrderDetailId`. Table `NewDetailsTable_noIndex` does not have any index.

I got on the first query: 31 seconds, 117 physical reads on the details table, 5 reads on the header table;

on the second query: 28 seconds, 5 physical read on the details table, 2 reads on the header table.

I still don't understand this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please use formatting to make your question easier to read.

Comment: If you provide the scripts for us to run ourselves that would probably make things easier. You can link them from pastebin or [gisthub](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: Using `SELECT *` almost always excludes the use of any non-clustered indices, since you want **all columns** from the data pages, thus it will almost certainly end up being a table scan (on a heap) or a clustered index scan (on a clustered table). If you would use just a few columns, then maybe indices might get used - especially if you have a **covered index** - an index that has all the columns that your query asks for (then there's no need at all to go back to the data - the heap or clustered index)

Comment: Which of the AdventureWorks Databases are you using? I seem to be lacking some columns in the ones I have currently installed.

Comment: I have some problems getting it to work on my box, so I can't reproduce. :( But looking at your script, and your description, can you clarify one thing for me: How many times do you run dbcc freesystemcache, etc.? You are aware that you have to run them before *each* select, not just in the beginning of the run?

Comment: Yes, I did run it before each select. I only ran each SELECT separately, anyway.

Comment: I noticed I had forgotten to answer one question. I'm using Adventure Works 2008

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change the size of your data-set. I agree with Marc_s that you should try to reduce the number of columns you select and see if that makes a difference.

Have you updated the table statistics? You can see in Management Studio how old they are  (or use `STATS_DATE`) and if any of them are from before you did your inserts from the staging table, they should certainly be updated.

Given that this is a test environment, you can safely run:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS NewDetailsTable WITH FULLSCAN
UPDATE STATISTICS newHeaderTable WITH FULLSCAN
....
```

In a live environment, especially on large tables, you might not want to do `FULLSCAN` but rather go for `SAMPLE <num> PERCENT`

Comment: Hi again, I could only look at this again today. I indeed tried to reduce the columns, and instead of SELECT * I made instead

Answer (score 0):

When I created the tables using the script you supplied it created objects of the following sizes.

- `NewDetailsTable_noIndex` 41485 data pages in the heap
- `NewDetailsTable` 41624 leaf level pages and 2 upper levels
- `newHeaderTable`  799 data pages in the heap
- `newHeaderTable_withClustIndex` 801 leaf level data pages
- `newHeaderTable_withIndex` 799 data pages in the heap, 59 leaf level NCI pages

You are selecting all 31,465 rows from the OrderHeader table and all related rows from the OrderDetail table without applying any filter.

If the execution plan were to use a nested loops join then this would require  31,465 index seeks into the `OrderDetails` table. Even for the `NewDetailsTable` case where an index does exist that would allow this it would be very inefficient to seek into each value individually. Each seek needs to navigate the index hierarchy meaning a minimum of 3 reads. When I forced this plan I ended up with 174,392 logical reads showing the average number of reads required to be actually over 5. This is about 4 times as many reads as scanning the table entirety (and non sequential IO too).

So having an index on `OrderDetails` that can be seeked into is not of particular benefit to this query both hash join and merge join will outperform the nested loops join that uses the seek.

Both hash and merge join need to scan each input one which means that all 6 of the execution plans end up with very similar IO. There are some minor differences across the various different versions of the header table but this is so much smaller than the Details table that they don't make any significant difference to the overall cost.

You might notice that for the version of the `Details` table with the Clustered Index logical reads are a bit higher than the actual number of leaf pages because SQL Server reads ahead the second level of the index too.

The clustered index version is able to use the merge join strategy because the index is already sorted by the joining column. Whilst this doesn't appear to lead to any measurable benefits in this case in terms of execution time it does provide a benefit in terms of not needing a memory grant and possibly needing to spill to `tempdb`.

Probably the most useful index you could add to the `Details` table would be one on `(SalesOrderID,SalesOrderDetailID)`. This would provide a narrower index for SQL Server to scan thus reducing the IO requirement but still cover both of the columns used in your revised query (without `*`)

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your answer is the kind I was hoping for to help me understand this. How can I force a plan, by the way? That seems to be an important part of this analysis and I'd like to know about it.

Comment: @AlexPinto - I used `INNER LOOP JOIN` in place of `JOIN` to get the nested loops plan. You also need to reverse the order of the 2 tables as using a join hint also enforces join order (i.e `... Header h INNER LOOP JOIN Details d ...`. . To see the size of tables and indexes you can use `dm_db_index_physical_stats`